# how to run Jar file in other system

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Actually i used below code created jar file of my Selenium project

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
    suites.add(Path of my xml file);

    testng.addListener(tla);

    testng.setTestSuites(suites);
    testng.run();
}
```

when i run the JAR file in other system it throws, "The System cannot find the path specified".

kindly advise on this and how can i run the "runnable jar" file in other system.

Comment: What kind of file path are you using, and on which system is the application launched ?

Comment: Which other system you mean? Linux?

Comment: Did you check the path of the xml file on the other system.
Maye be specified xml path in the code is not available on the other system.

Comment: Not linux, same windows machine @VladimirTikhomirov

Comment: @Berger file path is my local machine were i have stored the workspace

Comment: hi M.Schett i have checked and JAR file was created in my machine only. In my machine it was running but executing from other system displays the mentioned error.

Comment: check the created jar-File if all dependecies are packed

Comment: Maybe you specifiy a windows path and you want to execute app on linux ;)

Comment: @metar ya i have checked